# Any way to optimize following query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Just a quick question, how can i optimize following my SQL server query and also, any way to replace while loop while loop?...Thanks

```
DECLARE @TOTAL INT, @COUNT INT=1, @ID INT,@FROMDATE DATE= '2016-11-01', @TODATE= '2016-11-10'
SELECT @TOTAL = COUNT(1) 
FROM NUMBERS  
WHILE @COUNT <= @TOTAL  
BEGIN  
    SELECT @ID = ID 
    FROM #TEMP 
    WHERE ROW_ID = @COUNT  
    DECLARE @OUTPUT VARCHAR(MAX) = '';  
    EXEC SPSAMPLEPROC @ID, @FROMDATE, @TODATE, @OUTPUT OUTPUT; 
    SELECT @COUNT = @COUNT + 1;  
END
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and in it explain what it is you are trying to achieve (in words rather than code)?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want to call that stored procedure for each set of parameters, a while loop or a cursor is pretty much the only way to do this. The only option would be to *eliminate* that call to the stored procedure and use whatever functionality is inside that stored procedure in a set-based "inline" way in a SQL statement

Comment: The question is quick indeed, the answer is very long; it has to cover all bases since next to no information is given.